# Does Django CMS support taxonomies or tags?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am studying Python and Django, my final goal is to create an administration panel that manages 2 things:

- "dynamic article / item" (which can create types of forms to enter).
- "dynamic taxonomies / tags" (which can create categories or groupers of the data "of the form type").

I have seen the documentation of DjangoCMS but I cannot find the names of these concepts, could you guide me?

**thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much whatever you want to do. If you want to add to what a page gives you, extend the page;
http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/extending_page_title.html

I've used this to add images to pages, so you could use it to add tags or anything else you'd like.

Here's an example of attributing a colour to pages;

```
class PageColourExtension(PageExtension):
    """
    Extend the page model with a background image field.
    """
    page_colour = models.CharField(
        _("Base colour"),
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        choices=COLOUR_CHOICES,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        """
        Identify by the page it is tied to.

        @return: page name
        @rtype: str
        """
        return '%s' % self.extended_object


extension_pool.register(PageColourExtension)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if djanog-cms is the right tool for your task. It's main purpose is to manage hierarchical pages, and the content on these pages. You need to keep in mind that this concept is already there, and cannot be changed, only extended.

For your specific case, I would recommend to create an own `Article` model, and then use the `PlaceholderField`, on your article model - it allows really dynamic content to be created, in the same fashion as when used on cms pages. See [django-cms placeholder outside the cms docs](https://djangocms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to/placeholders/) for how to do that.

If you want to use django-cms and your custom application/article app alongside, you can use an app-hook to embed your urls under a cms page. See docs [djanog-cms apphooks](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html)